# Determine if method is called from a view or controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in my Application controller I have a method to check if the current user is authorized for the action. I use this method both from other controllers and from views. How can I determine if the method is called from a view or a controller?

This is needed because the response is different (show alert and redirect when from controller, hide link when from view). Probably I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here and I should maybe solve it completely different?

Application controller:

```
  helper_method :is_allowed

    # Check if current user is allowed to perform action
  def is_allowed(required_level)
    # Required level is level and all levels above (1=high, 3=low)
    # level 1: user
    # level 2: company_admin
    # level 3: admin
    case required_level
        when 'company_admin'
            unless current_user.role == 'company_admin' || current_user.role == 'admin'
              flash[:alert] = I18n.t(:not_allowed)
              redirect_to root_path
            end
        when 'admin'
            unless current_user.role == 'admin'
              flash[:alert] = I18n.t(:not_allowed)
              redirect_to root_path
            end
        end
  end
```

Call from other controller (this works):

```
  before_filter :only => [:destroy] do |c| c.is_allowed 'company_admin' end
```

Call from view (does work, but should not redirect, but only hide link):

```
<% if is_allowed('company_admin') %>
  <td><%= link_to I18n.t(:delete), relation, :method => :delete, :confirm => I18n.t(:sure) %></td>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use separate helpers.

The `View` context is different than the `Controller` context. Mixing these contexts breaks the MVC pattern.

Comment: But basically they will do the same, are separate helpers not against the DRY principle?

Comment: They don't do the same thing, otherwise you wouldn't have to distinguish whether you are calling the helper from the controller or the view. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Checking `self`'s inheritance chain might work:

```
case self
when ActionController then ...
when ActionView then ...
end
```

or maybe query `self.is_a?(ActionController)` or `self.kind_of?(ActionController)`.

Let me know how things turn out!